# Adding together two unit balls

Tags: geometry, normed-spaces, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, differential

Suppose I have a norm which is composed of two norms in a convex fashion:

$$||x|| = \alpha ||x||_1 + (1-\alpha)||x||_2,$$
where $\alpha \in [0,1]$. Now suppose I'm interested in finding the subdifferential of $||x||$ at zero, i.e, the unit ball of the dual norm. Can I derive the unit ball of $||x\|$ in terms of those for $||x||_1$ and $||x||_2$? These are not the traditional $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norms, but generic norms. Formally, I'm looking to derive the set

$$B_{||\cdot||^*}[0,1] = \{y: ||y||^* \leq 1\}$$

in terms of $B_{||\cdot||_1^*}[0,1]$ and $B_{||\cdot||_2^*}[0,1]$.

Comment: Are those p-norms? If not, I’d recommend writing 1 and 2 for the subscripts, to avoid confusion. Also, are you looking for more than $\alpha ||x||_p + (1-\alpha)||x||_q=1$? In what way do you employ “derive”?

Comment: @Bcpicao changed it. I've also added more information about exactly what I'm after.

Comment: The $\alpha$ is fixed here?

Comment: @jwhite yes, it's a fixed constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new norm you've described makes your new space sit isometrically as a subspace of a $\oplus_1$ sum, so the dual will be a quotient of an $\oplus_\infty$ sum. The quotient involves taking an infimum over decompositions, so the result is potentially intractable.

Since $\|\cdot\|$ is equal to either $\|\cdot\|_1$ or $\|\cdot\|_2$ if $\alpha\in \{0,1\}$, I will assume $0<\alpha<1$.

**POINT $1$** We know that if $E$ is a subspace of $F$, then $E^*=F^*/E^\perp$, where $E^\perp=\{f^*\in F^*:f^*|_E\equiv 0\}$. That is, duals of subspaces are quotients (and duals of quotients are subspaces, but we won't use that here).

More generally, if $j:G\to F$ is an isometric embedding (a linear operator with $\|j(g)\|_F=\|g\|_G$ for all $g\in G$), then $G^*\approx F^*/j(G)^\perp=F^*/\ker(j^*)$, where $\approx$ denotes isometric isomorphism. That's because $G$ is isometrically isomorphic to $E:=j(G)$ (via $j$, of course), so $G^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $E^*=F^*/j(G)^\perp$, and $j(G)^\perp=\ker(j^*)$ by usual nonsense. In fact, $j^*$ can be thought of as the quotient map from $F^*$ to $F^*/\ker(j^*)\approx G^*$, in the sense that $$\|g^*\|_{G^*}=\inf\{\|f^*\|_{F^*}:j^*f^*=g^*\}.$$

**POINT $2$** If $(E,e)$ and $(F,f)$ are Banach spaces, then for $1\leqslant p\leqslant \infty$ and $q$ with $1/p+1/q=1$, $$((E,e)\oplus_p (F,f))^*=(E^*,e^*)\oplus_q (F^*,f^*).$$

Suppose we have $\alpha\in [0,1]$ and two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$, $\|\cdot\|_2$ on the same vector space $X$ such that $(X, \|\cdot\|_1)$, $(X, \|\cdot\|_2)$ are Banach spaces. To make things prettier, let $X_1$ denote $X$ endowed with the norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ and let $X_2$ denote $X$ endowed with the norm $\|\cdot\|_2$. Similarly, let $X_1^*$, $X^*_2$ denote $X^*$ endowed with $\|\cdot\|^*_1$, $\|\cdot\|_2^*$, respectively. Define $j:X\to X_1\oplus_1 X_2$ by $$j(x)=(\alpha x, (1-\alpha)x).$$  Define a new norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$ by $$\|x\|=\|j(x)\|=\alpha \|x\|_1+(1-\alpha)\|x\|_2.$$  So $j:(X, \|\cdot\|)\to X_1\oplus_1 X_2$ is an isometry (we forced this with the definition of $\|\cdot\|$). Combining the first two points, $(X^*, \|\cdot\|^*)$ is isometrically identifiable with $$(X_1\oplus_1 X_2)^*/\ker(j^*) = (X^*_1\oplus_\infty X^*_2)/\ker(j^*).$$

Note that $j^*:X^*_1\oplus_\infty X^*_2\to X^*$ is given by $$j^*(x^*_1,x^*_2)=\alpha x^*_1+(1-\alpha)x^*_2.$$ Indeed, \begin{align*}(\alpha x^*_1+(1-\alpha)x^*_2)(x)=x^*_1(\alpha x)+x^*_2((1-\alpha)x)=(x^*_1,x^*_2)j(x). \end{align*}

So for any $x^*\in X^*$, we have from point $1$ that $$\|x^*\|^* = \inf\{\max\{\|x^*_1\|^*, \|x^*_2\|^*_2\}:x^*_1,x^*_2\in X^*,\alpha x^*_1+(1-\alpha)x^*_2=x^*\}.$$  This can be rewritten as $$\|x^*\|^* = \inf\Bigl\{\max\bigl\{\bigl\|\frac{x^*-y^*}{\alpha}+y^*\bigr\|_1^*,\|y^*\|_2^*\bigr\}: y^*\in X^*\Bigr\},$$ although I'm not sure if that's any more tractable than the preceding expression.

Two other equivalent expressions would be $$\|x^*\|^* = \inf\Bigl\{\max\{\alpha^{-1}\|x^*_1\|^*_1, (1-\alpha)^{-1}\|x^*_2\|^*_2\}:x^*_1,x^*_2\in X^*, x^*_1+x^*_2=x^*\Bigr\},$$ or $$\|x^*\|^* = \inf\Bigl\{\max\{\alpha^{-1}\|y^*\|^*_1, (1-\alpha)^{-1}\|x^*-y^*\|^*_2\}:y^*\in X^*\Bigr\}.$$

Comment: What are the inf and max over?

Comment: The max is from the $\oplus_\infty$ norm, so it is always of the two subsequent expressions explicitly enclosed in the inner braces immediately following the max. The inf is over all vector or pairs of vectors satisfying the rightmost constraint in the outer braces. Ie, $\inf\Bigl\{\max \{\text{thing1}, \text{thing2}\}:\text{Constraint}\Bigr\}$. Max is of thing1, thing2, inf is over everything satisfying Constraint.

Comment: From point 1, the infimum is coming from $\|g^*\|^*=\inf \{\|f^*\|:j^*f^*=g^*\}$. The different constraints come from the different, equivalent ways to express the constraint $j^*(x^*_1,x^*_2)=x^*$ for our particular choices.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be unit ball of your new dual norm.
Then $D = \partial \|\cdot\|(0)$.
Let $D_i$ be the unit ball of the dual norm of $\|\cdot\|_i$.
Using the sum rule for the subdifferential, we have

$$ D = \alpha D_1 + (1-\alpha) D_2.$$